# Is there a Unicode character to describe a relationship involving a dependency?

Tags: javascript, php, unicode, ascii, notation

Many ASCII and Unicode characters signify relationships:

- `>` is greater than
- `<` is less than
- `=` is equal to
- `≠` is not equal to
- `∈` is a member of
- `∉` is not a member of

Is there a character (which I can use in documentation or comments to describe code architecture in javascript or PHP) which signifies ***relies on dependency***?

- x `[relies on dependency]` y

The closest thing I have come up with is:

- `∋` [`U+220B`] (ie. `contains` or `contains as member`)

Can I employ the following notation

- `x ∋ y`

and it will describe ***x relies on the dependency y***?

Do either javascript or PHP (or lower level programming languages) have a more specific notation for describing when one script always depends on (or includes) another modular script?

---

## Update 1

I have now also found the *double turnstile*:

- `⊨` [`U+22A8`] (ie. `entails`)

(See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile)

I think `∋` and `⊨` are both reasonable candidates but neither convey precisely the relationship I am looking to describe.

---

## Update 2

I have come across another symbol called *two joined squares*:

- `⧉` [`U+29C9`] (`two joined squares`)

I have been unable (so far) to determine the meaning of this symbol, though, pictorially, at least, it *does* suggest the kind of relationship I am looking to describe - that is, the upper left square incorporates part of the lower right square.

---

## Update 3

Returning to this question after nearly two and half years...

There is a mathematical symbol featuring two concentric circles:

- `⊚` [`U+229A`] (`Circled Ring Operator`)

which no-one seems to know the meaning of, but which might suitably convey *a module contained within another module* (and imply that either the former is a dependency of the latter or vice versa).

Two points:

- `⊚` [`U+229A`] is not the better-known **Bullseye** (`◎`) [`U+25CE`], though perhaps either would do
- other circular symbols which display another shape within the circle include:

  - `⊙` [`U+2299`]
  - `⦿` [`U+29BF`]
  - `◔` [`U+25D4`]

Answer (score 1):

I am 3.5 years too late...but why don't you use "succeed" (≻) or "preceed" (≺)?

So "C" ≺ "D" means "C" preceeds "D", or "C" comes before "D". "D" cannot exist without "C".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand "calls on the dependency*" concept...

In mathematics, we have these relations:

```
A ⇒ B is like saying "A implies B" or "B follows from A".

A ∵ B is like saying "A is true because B is true".

A ∴ B is like saying "Because A is true, therefore B is true".
```

But I am afraid they are not exactly the answer you ask for...

Comment: Thanks. A dependency is simply a file required by another file. In this case I want to indicate that  **Module A** relies upon **Submodule J** and **Submodule K** as dependencies.